# Problem with inheritance when using options pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

in my ASP.NET Core application, I have two options classes like in this example:

```
public class ParentOptions
{
    [Required]
    public string option1 { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    public string option2 { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class ChildOptions : ParentOptions
{
    [Required]
    public string option3 { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    public string option4 { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

In my case, I need the `ChildOptions` in a console application because they contain the credentials which the application uses to authenticate against an API. In another application inside the same solution, these options are not needed because the credentials come from somewhere else. However, since all the remaining options are still needed in both applications, I defined them in the `ParentOptions`.

In the application root of the console application, I added the options like this:

```
services.AddOptions<ChildOptions>()
    .Bind(context.Configuration.GetRequiredSection("ChildOptions"))
    .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

This allows me to inject a `IOptions<ChildOptions>` wherever I need it. Unfortunately, this does not allow me to inject a `IOptions<ParentOptions>`, despite that fact that a `IOptions<ChildOptions>` would work perfectly fine in that case. Since both the console application and the other application in my solution share some of the same functionality, every class which needs a `IOptions<ParentOptions>` no longer works inside the console application because of this problem.

The only solution I found so far is to basically force it to use `IOptions<ChildOptions>` as `IOptions<ParentOptions>` like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IOptions<ParentOptions>>((IServiceProvider provider) =>
    provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ChildOptions>>());
```

Why does this not already work out of the box and is my solution really the proper way to do it, or is there a better solution?

Comment: How do you want to use `ParentOptions`? If two different sections inherit from it, which section would you expect to get? There's no expectation that `AddOptions<ChildOptions>()` would register all parent types up to `Object`. Options are *configuration* objects, that represent different configuration sections. There's no inheritance relation between two different configuration sections.

Comment: Inheritance isn't a composition mechanism. Inheritance is an `is-a` relation, not `has-a`. In your case it seems that the credentials need their own settings, at the same level as the other options, eg `"ConsoleOptions":{ "user":"blah", "pass":"blah", "OtherOptions":{......}}`. You can map `ConsoleOptions` to an object that has an `OtherOptions` property

Comment: A `is-a` relation is exactly what I have here and what I intended to have. `ChildOptions` are also `ParentOptions` because they contain every property that `ParentOptions` also contains. To me, this seems like a text-book example of inheritance. Technically, the credentials also belong into the same section because this section contains all the settings related to the API I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Additionally, I do not have two different sections in the same application. My console application is only supposed to have the `ChildOptions` while the other application only has the `ParentOptions` section in its configuration. Therefore, which section I expect to get should be pretty clear because there is only one section in each application.

Comment: You can argue that the library is wrong and never get anywhere, or you can adapt your code to the way the library works. Settings are key/value pairs, not objects. Sections aren't objects. Inheritance has no meaning when there are no objects. Options is one way to to gather and use the settings as objects

Comment: `which section I expect to get should be pretty clear` what's the problem with just registering `ChildOptions` then? You can pass that anywhere `ParentOptions` is needed. Which code *in that application* expects an `IOptions<ParentOptions>`? Other applications should register their own config objects

Comment: Do the shared classes depend too much on DI perhaps? You wouldn't have this problem it they received a `ParentOptions` instead of `IOption<ParentOptions>`

Comment: I have a few projects which are shared between both applications. In those shared projects, multiple classes expect an `IOptions<ParentOptions>`. I cannot simply modify them to expect an `IOptions<ChildOptions>` instead because `ChildOptions` is defined in the console application since it is not needed anywhere else. What do you mean by saying "Do the shared classes depend too much on DI perhaps"? These classes need access to the options because otherwise they could not interact with the 3rd party API.